# Compile error for QT 5.2.1; expected unqualified-id before 'delete'

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, qt5

I'm trying to compile `QT 5.2.1` for an older Linux distro (Suse Linux Enterprise 11) and after a while I receive the error below:

```
In file included from qxcbxsettings.cpp:46:0:  
/usr/include/X11/extensions/XIproto.h:1825:17: 
    error: expected unqualified-id before 'delete'  
BOOL        delete;
```

I'm more or less confident this is caused by the fact that "delete" is a reserved word for C++. If this header would be my own, I would simply rename delete to something else, but of course it is not an option in case of an X11 header file.
Any ideas how can I force `gcc` to compile as plain C for this header? All I found is a configure option `-no-c++11` for qt's configure script, but that did not make a difference.

Comment: Could you please give us the code before and after `qxcbxsettings.cpp:46`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete is a reserved keyword in C++, There is bug reported related to X11/extensions/XIproto.h file [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/x11proto-input/+bug/284603)

They also provided [patch](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/inputproto/diff/?id=fabe087cebb11c6a2600e57c6f7a52fda2efea29) for same

So you need to apply patch for compiling further patch is like

```
+#if defined(__cplusplus) || defined(c_plusplus)
+    BOOL        c_delete;
+#else
     BOOL        delete;
+#endif
```